# Oracle SQL Merge TW

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

So I have two tables. They're kinda messy and I am trying to get them merged so I don't have multiple rows for the same user ID.

Basically I want something like this. Only for a specific supplier ID too.

```
USER_ID          Attribute                    Value
----------         -------                   -------------
pqp72x      name, phone, email, locale       Barbosa, Miller S, 874-346-8907,...   

Supplier_ID          
----------
005356613
```

There are the two tables.

```
Table A
USER_ID     Attribute  Value
----------  -------  -------------
pqp72x      name     Barbosa, Miller S
pqp72x      phone    874-346-8907
pqp72x      email    bmiller@catsalot.org
pqp72x      locale   US
ewp85r      name     Green, Kevin
ewp85r      phone    932-386-3914
ewp85r      email    gkevin@catsalot.org
ewp85r      locale   US

Table B
USER_ID     Supplier ID  
----------  -------  
pqp72x      005356613
ewp85r      005356613
ksas23      273984729
24jsok      373499435
```

How would I do this? I am very lost.

Comment: See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques for a list of string aggregation techniques.  Which one you use will depend on the Oracle version, the potential length of the strings, whether you want an officially supported function, whether you can create additional PL/SQL objects or whether you are limited to a pure SQL solution among others.

Comment: Very good guide. That solved my issue. Thanks!